# Is the ring $(Z_p[[X]] \otimes Q_p)/(X-p)^r$ principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]] \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}_p$ and the ideal generated by $(X-p)^r$ (for some integer $r$).

Is the following true : for all integer $r$, the ring
$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]] \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}_p}{(X-p)^r} $$
is principal ?

I can see that for $r=1$, the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q_p}$ (so it is principal), but I don't know when $r \geq 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the change of variables $T = X - p$ yields an isomorphism
$$\mathbb Z_p[[X]] \cong \mathbb Z_p[[T]].$$ (The point here is that $p$ lies
in the maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z_p$.)

So your ring is isomorphic to
$\mathbb Q_p[T]/(T^r),$ which you can easily verify is principal.